# how to use python sys.argv

Tags: python, csv, import, argv

how to use python sys.argv

I want to leave the result as the file name I want.

```
import pymssql
import csv
import sys

dbname = sys.argv[1]
conn = pymssql.connect(host='rds.amazonaws.com', user='asdf', password='asdf', database= dbname, charset='utf8')
curs = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * from usertable with(nolock);"
f = open('dbname_result.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(f)
curs.execute(sql)
rows = curs.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    wr.writerow(row)
    
conn.commit()
conn.close()
f.close()
```

result

```
python test.py userdb01  
-> dbname_result.csv
```

But the result that I hope...

```
python test.py userdb01  
-> userdb01_result.csv
```

Comment: Your use of ```sys.argv``` was fine. You need to use an f-string (formatted string) for the filename: ```f = open(f'{dbname}_result.csv', 'w')```, if you have Python 3.6 or later.

Comment: I'm still using Python 2.7.16. but I'll try. @sj95126

Comment: OK, then you could just do: ```f = open(dbname + '_result.csv', 'w')```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did the one I provided below work for you? If so please mark an answer or create one and mark it for those that find your question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sj95126 minimally described in a comment, you are not evaluating the value of `dbname` as a variable. You are passing it as a constant string value.

If you are using Python 3+ you can use the f-string as described...

`f = open(f'{dbname}_result.csv', 'w')`

If you are using Python 2 or 3 you can use multiple methods but I prefer `str.format` if I'm needing to be compatible across versions.

`f = open('{}_result.csv'.format(dbname), 'w')`